# Z-index of background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

On this site: http://www.effic.be/wordpress/

I have an arrow that points to the first widget on the homepage.

This is the code:

**1. HTML**

```
<div class="home-full">
    <div class="home-top">
        <div class="site-inner">
            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="home-bottom">
                    <section id="featured-page-advanced-2">Widget 1 content</section>
                    <section id="featured-page-advanced-3">Widget 2 content</section>
                    <section id="featured-page-advanced-4">Widget 3 content</section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2. CSS**

```
.home-full {
    background-image: url(/wordpress/wp-content/themes/enterprise-pro/images/arrow.png);
    background-position: 36% 47%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.site-inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -999999;
}

.home-bottom {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

I need the arrow to display as it is now. It starts in the "home top" div and points to the "featured-page-advanced-2" section. That's why I added the "home full" div with the arrow background.

My problem: my widgets (titles and buttons) are no longer clickable. The z-index causes the "home-full" div to be in front.

Is there a way to resolve this? I spent all afternoon on it : )

Thank you!
Stefaan

Comment: Try removing the z-index

Comment: Then the arrow disappears behind the grey background of the 3 widgets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I was not able to make it through fiddle so I made these changes using firebug, this is the same as I mentioned above and the arrow is showing please go through it maybe u missed something out and please call me Ameen :)

Comment: I was still using 'background-image' instead of 'background'. So stupid... Thank you Ameen, you made my day! Incredible thing, to get help from across the globe ; )

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the arrow to the home-full div add the arrow to the "home-top widget-area" div using :before or :after and give position relative to this parent and  remove the z-index : -9999px from the .site-inner div

```
home-top widget-area{
    position:relative
}

home-top.widget-area:after{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:55px;
    content:'';
    background:url("/wordpress/wp-content/themes/enterprise-pro/images/arrow.png") no-repeat;
    width:57px;
    height:101px;

    }
```

If the arrow is still hidden behind the lower div section trying increasing z-index in the :after css code

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, the background doesn't show. This is my code now:

`.home-top widget-area:after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 55px;
    content: '';
    background-image: url(/wordpress/wp-content/themes/enterprise-pro/images/arrow.png) no-repeat;
    width: 57px;
    height: 101px;
    z-index: 999999;
}`

Comment: Did u add position relative to home-top.widget-area div? According to the code its looks like there is a syntax error .home-topwidget-area:after. It looks like you missed the dot syntax between top and widget. Also use jsfiddle to upload code, it would be easy to check

Comment: I cannot see the result, you need to add the html, css, and the result of this will be displayed in the result box...then I will be able to edit and see the code :)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Lj3L5kzo/2/ I pasted the whole body html and my whole style.css, otherwise it wouldn't work. The .home-top.widget-area:after starts on line 1309. Thank you for your patience Muhammad, I'm only a beginner : )

Comment: I have added the same changes in the fiddle line 1301, the first 2 css code and remember to remove the z-index -9999px from the div below

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this :

```
background-size : cover
```

The background-size property specifies the size of the background images. Syntax :

```
background-size: auto|length|cover|contain|initial|inheri
```

Doc : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: That made the arrow extremely big, but didn't solve my problem. The home-full div is pretty big...